# Grep a list of files from a file and print specific part of the line with condition

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

I would like to extract the file paths from different directories listed inside a file after "FILE_PATHS",then extract a specific part of these file names based on a condition. For example:

```
$ grep ^FILE_PATHS file.txt
FILE_PATHS /james/families/MOTHER/analyses/trait 
FILE_PATHS /james/families/SIB/analyses/BROTHER/trait 
FILE_PATHS /james/families/REL/analyses/AUNT/trait 
FILE_PATHS /james/families/FATHER/analyses/trait
```

From this list of file paths, I would like to extract a specific part of the file name "MOTHER", "SIB", "REL", "FATHER", and then if this part is equal to "SIB" print "BROTHER", if it is equal to "REL" print "AUNT", otherwise (for "MOTHER" and "FATHER") print "MOTHER" and "FATHER". 
The only files that have a path different from the rest are the ones equal to "SIB" and "REL" in the 4th field, however the complication is that there are many options for what the value on the 6th field could be, so I am looking for a solution where I don't need to specify the values of "BROTHER" and "AUNT" in the 6th field, but that would just print my 6th field.

So it would be something like this:

```
cat file.txt | while read line; do
if [ `echo "$line" | grep ^FILE_PATHS file.txt | cut -d' ' -f 2 | cut -d '/' -f4 -eq "BROTHER" | "REL" `  ]

then
    grep ^FILE_PATHS file.txt | cut -d' ' -f 2 | cut -d '/' -f5
else
    grep ^FILE_PATHS file.txt | cut -d' ' -f 2 | cut -d '/' -f4
fi; done
```

This is full of errors and incorrect, but maybe I have the wrong approach all together, and I am sure there is a smart way of doing this but I am totally new to BASH, is there a better approach I am not seeing?

Comment: To clarify, do you want to print the component *after* SIB or REL (which might presumably be SISTER or UNCLE or something else as well)?

Comment: Only the components, i.e.: MOTHER, BROTHER, AUNT, FATHER..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work for you

```
your grep....|awk -F/ '{$4=$4=="REL"?"AUNT":$4;$4=$4=="SIB"?"BROTHER":$4;print $4}'
```

actually you could combine your grep into awk like:

```
awk -F/ '/^FILE_PATHS/{$4=$4=="REL"?"AUNT":$4;$4=$4=="SIB"?"BROTHER":$4;print $4}' file.txt
```

output from your example:

```
MOTHER
BROTHER
AUNT
FATHER
```

show how it work:

```
kent$  cat o
FILE_PATHS /james/families/MOTHER/analyses/trait 
FILE_PATHS /james/families/SIB/analyses/BROTHER/trait 
FILE_PATHS /james/families/REL/analyses/AUNT/trait 
FILE_PATHS /james/families/FATHER/analyses/trait

kent$  awk -F/ '/^FILE_PATHS/{$4=$4=="REL"?"AUNT":$4;$4=$4=="SIB"?"BROTHER":$4;print $4}'  o
MOTHER
BROTHER
AUNT
FATHER
```

**EDIT Again**

> If the value on the 3rd field is SIB or REL I would like to print
>   whatever is in the fifth field

I would say it should be 4th field is SIB/REL, then print 6th. since the first field is FILE_PATHS.

now this line works:

```
  awk -F/ '/^FILE_PATHS/{$4=$4~"^(REL|SIB)$"?$6:$4;print $4}' file.txt
```

test!!:

```
kent$  cat o
FILE_PATHS /james/families/MOTHER/analyses/trait 
FILE_PATHS /james/families/SIB/analyses/BROTHER/trait 
FILE_PATHS /james/families/REL/analyses/AUNT/trait 
FILE_PATHS /james/families/FATHER/analyses/trait

kent$  awk -F/ '/^FILE_PATHS/{$4=$4~"^(REL|SIB)$"?$6:$4;print $4}' o
MOTHER
BROTHER
AUNT
FATHER
```

Comment: Hi Kent, thank you. The code is giving me MOTHER, SIB, REL, FATHER though, while what I would like is MOTHER, BROTHER, AUNT, FATHER...

Comment: @user1642995 either you did the test wrong, or I wrote the code wrong. I got the expected output here.. :(

Comment: It is my fault probably, the folders have other subdirectories, so the whole paths would be: $ grep ^FILE_PATHS file.txt
FILE_PATHS /james/families/MOTHER/analyses/trait
FILE_PATHS /james/families/SIB/analyses/BROTHER/trait
FILE_PATHS /james/families/REL/analyses/AUNT/trait
FILE_PATHS /james/families/FATHER/analyses/trait

Comment: @user1642995 that line worked, see answer update, I copied the output

Comment: If the value on the 3rd field is SIB or REL I would like to print whatever is in the fifth field (It varies each time, so I would like to not have to specify whether it is a 'BROTHER' or an 'AUNT' if this is at all possible...) Thank you again!

Comment: @user1642995 it wastes peoples time when you don't ask the question you actually want the answer too!

Comment: @user1642995 check the **EDIT Again** section in my answer.

Comment: KENT, PERFECT, THIS   "awk -F/ '/^FILE_PATHS/{$4=$4~"^(REL|SIB)$"?$6:$4;print $4}' file.txt" DOES EXACTLY WHAT I WANTED!! ..sorry for the confusions

Answer (score 1):

Easy using `sed` just capture the penultimate directory:

```
$ sed -r '/^FILE_PATHS/s#.*/(\w+)/.*#\1#' file
MOTHER
BROTHER
AUNT
FATHER
```

**Edit:** if it's not always the penultimate directory:

```
$ grep "^FILE_PATHS" file | egrep -o "(MOTHER|BROTHER|AUNT|FATHER)"
MOTHER
BROTHER
AUNT
FATHER
```

Comment: Hi sudo, thank you, I just used this as an example but the file paths is not constantly the penultimate but it varies...

Comment: Your question should reflect that then, see edit. Can multiple matches appear one line i.e `/james/families/MOTHER/AUNT/trait/`?

Comment: Ok I will edit now. No there can't exist /james/families/MOTHER/AUNT/trait/ , basically it is only the two values of 'SIB' and 'REL' that act differently from the rest and have different paths.

Comment: If that is the case then `SIB` and `REL` don't matter, just `grep` for what you are actually looking for like my second answer does!

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you don't have any upper case letters except in the words you're looking for:

```
sed '/^FILE_PATHS/!d; s/^FILE_PATHS//; s/[^A-Z]//g; s/^SIB\|REL//' filename
```